# quote symbol parsing

Tags: c++

i have file like this

```
"a",205    
"b",214    
"c",223    
""",13
```

and i need to parse it 
i read line by line to str and i have to convert second character  from string to integer, but when it comes to quote <"> character it throws an exception **string subscript out of range**.

```
std::string STRING;
std::ifstream infile;
std::vector < std::string > tokens;
infile.open (Filename);

unsigned int x; 
while(! infile.eof()) 
{
    std::getline(infile,STRING); 
    tokens = Utility::splitString(STRING,',');//array of tokens
    x = (unsigned int)tokens[0][1];//convert first tokens,second character to uint
}
```

I think it is something with escape sequence.

Comment: A slightly larger snippet of code would help here. What is str[0][1] supposed to be? Is this a 2-dimensional string?

Comment: What stand your two indices for? What concrete data type is `str` of? Could you please provide some more code?

Comment: Did you have a look at the contents of `STRING` and `tokens`?

Comment: "std::vector tokens;" is not a valid declaration of anything.  vector needs a type argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `tokens[0][1]` gets the second character of the first string, which is out of range.
2. The type cast is not the way to convert. use atoi().

Comment: I think, he's searching for the ASCII value of the character and does not want to "cast" a string representation of a number to an integer.

Comment: oh thanks all it is my fault I didn't noticed that in file there is line containing "," and I am spliting string by ','